# Haskell type error message

Tags: haskell, types, typeerror

For the past couple of days I've been trying to learn Haskell. While I'm slowly getting better but I'm finding it hard to reason with Haskell's IO, probably due to my lack of knowledge. I've been trying to write a simple todo list program. Here's what I've got:

```
tadd todo = do
    td <- getLine
    td:todo

tdel todo = do
    trem <- getLine
    let rid = read trem :: Int
    [todo !! x | x <- [0..(length todo-1)], not $ x == rid]

tls todo = do
    mapM putStrLn [ (show x) ++ (todo !! x) | x <- [0..(length todo -1)] ]
    todo

mtodo "add" todo = tadd todo
mtodo "del" todo = tdel todo
mtodo "ls"  todo = tls todo


bege = do
    com <- getLine
    mtodo com []

main = bege
```

I was excepting the mtodo to be `mtodo :: [IO String] -> [IO String] -> [IO String]`
and tadd, tdel, tls to be `:: [IO String] -> [IO String]`.

Instead I just get this scary error messsage

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( todo.hs, todo.o )

todo.hs:3:9:
    Couldn't match type `[]' with `IO'
    Expected type: IO String
      Actual type: [String]
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: td : todo
    In the expression:
      do { td <- getLine;
           td : todo }
    In an equation for `tadd':
        tadd todo
          = do { td <- getLine;
                 td : todo }

todo.hs:8:9:
    Couldn't match expected type `IO' with actual type `[]'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      [todo !! x | x <- [0 .. (length todo - 1)], not $ x == rid]
    In the expression:
      do { trem <- getLine;
           let rid = ...;
           [todo !! x | x <- [0 .. (length todo - 1)], not $ x == rid] }
    In an equation for `tdel':
        tdel todo
          = do { trem <- getLine;
                 let rid = ...;
                 [todo !! x | x <- [0 .. (length todo - 1)], not $ x == rid] }

todo.hs:12:9:
    Couldn't match type `[]' with `IO'
    Expected type: IO [Char]
      Actual type: [[Char]]
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: todo
    In the expression:
      do { mapM
             putStrLn [(show x) ++ (todo !! x) | x <- [0 .. (length todo - 1)]];
           todo }
    In an equation for `tls':
        tls todo
          = do { mapM
                   putStrLn [(show x) ++ (todo !! x) | x <- [0 .. (length todo - 1)]];
                 todo }
```

Any ideas what's wrong with my types? (Also - is there anything I should change?). Thanks

Comment: Explicitly type things! It'll make it much easier to reason when you're confused, because it forces you to ask yourself questions like *which type do I want this to return?* and *what is this thing?*.

Comment: By the way, it's generally preferred to use spaces instead of tabs for Haskell code, and not just because it works better for copy+paste into a SO question. :] Haskell cares about alignment, not just indentation, and tabs are interpreted in a way that probably doesn't match how your editor displays them.

Comment: I recommend you read my [tutorial on IO](http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/01/introduction-to-haskell-io.html), which will slowly you walk you through the types so you can understand the type errors better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at this code:

```
tadd todo = do
    td <- getLine
    td:todo
```

The problem is that you have `td:todo` as a line by itself; you're using `getLine`, so the whole block should be using `IO`, but your last line is a list. This is what the "can't match" errors are about--the code seems to say that `IO` and `[]` should be the same thing, but of course they aren't.

To lift a value into the monadic context in order to use it as the result value of the `do` block, use the function `return`:

```
tadd todo = do
    td <- getLine
    return $ td:todo
```

This will give `tadd` the type `[String] -> IO [String]`. This isn't what you seem to expect the type to be, but from what you've written I don't think you want to be using `[IO String]`.

The same applies to the list comprehension in `tdel` and the final `todo` in `tls`.

Also, your expected type here is off:

```
mtodo :: [IO String] -> [IO String] -> [IO String]
mtodo "add" todo = tadd todo
mtodo "del" todo = tdel todo
mtodo "ls"  todo = tls todo
```

The first argument is clearly a `String` here, so based on the above you probably want `mtodo :: String -> [String] -> IO [String]`

This is probably also not what you want:

```
bege = do
    com <- getLine
    mtodo com []
```

---

A few other notes:

Based on the rest of the code you seem to want an interactive program, but this will run it only once. What you probably want instead is something like this:

```
bege todo = do
    com <- getLine
    todo' <- mtodo com todo
    bege todo'

main = bege []
```

Your list comprehension `[todo !! x | x <- [0..(length todo-1)], not $ x == rid]` is very inefficient and not idiomatic at all. As a rule of thumb, if you're still learning Haskell you should probably never use `(!!)` unless you're discarding the list afterward. Haskell lists are linear sequences, so indexing requires traversing everything up to that point. Not really the best data structure for what you're doing, but you should at least find some way to do that that doesn't require traversing the list multiple times.

As an example of avoiding `(!!)`, you could rewrite `mapM putStrLn [ (show x) ++ (todo !! x) | x <- [0..(length todo -1)] ]` as `mapM_ putStrLn $ zipWith (\n t -> show n ++ t) [0..] todo`, which avoids all the confusing and superfluous stuff like indexing and worrying about the length of the list, as well as traversing the list only once, instead of traversing it first to compute the length, then partially traversing it up to each item to print it.

This is more a matter of taste, but instead of writing this:

```
mtodo "add" todo = tadd todo
mtodo "del" todo = tdel todo
mtodo "ls"  todo = tls todo
```

You could abbreviate it as:

```
mtodo "add" = tadd
mtodo "del" = tdel
mtodo "ls"  = tls
```

...which means exactly the same thing, and is arguably clearer by reducing excess noise and making it obvious that all it's doing is selecting one of several other functions based on the string given.

Also, the `let rid = read trem :: Int` bit is unnecessary--just use the function `readLn` instead of `getLine`, which does exactly what you want here. Also, the type annotation is probably unnecessary (and distracting) because the type should be inferred based on what you do with the result.

Comment: It was meant to be interactive indeed.. I just removed my attempts from the question as it was broken enough without them. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn about return. All you need to do to get this to compile is to add return to the last line of tadd, tdel and tls.

You'll get better error messages if you use explicit type signatures.

```
tadd :: [String] -> IO [String]
tadd todo = do
  td <- getLine
  return (td:todo)
```

In this case, `(td:todo)` has type `[String]`, you need to add return to bring it into the IO monad, which is what the function needs to return. When you use do notation, each line needs to have a type in the monad you're in (except for the ones starting with let), in this case that's IO.

tdel and tls have exactly the same problem.

```
tdel :: [String] -> IO [String]
tdel todo = do
  trem <- getLine
  let rid = read trem :: Int
  return [todo !! x | x <- [0..(length todo-1)], not $ x == rid]

tls :: [String] -> IO [String]
tls todo = do
  mapM putStrLn [ (show x) ++ (todo !! x) | x <- [0..(length todo -1)] ]
  return todo
```